# What sources of damage to detonators are doubled in uprising?

Tags: overwatch

Now that the uprising gamemode is back, I noticed something. Even heros that can't deal headshot damage still deal critical damage to the large bombs (detonators) that drop to blow up the payload (for example bastion turret form).

However, how does this apply to ultimates such as high noon, meis' and other non-projectile/hitscan based hero ability (and junkrats'). What hero's can still not deal "critical" damage to the detonator?

Answer (score 4):

Every source of damage will deal critical damage **to a Detonator's core**.

Comment: Does this include damage instances that aren't targetted at specific locations - such as junkrats trap - or will it only apply to damage instances that impace or deal damage at a location that deals "critical damage"?